# how to override Catalog\Category\Abstract.php

Tags: blocks, overrides

I want to override Catalog\Category\Abstract.php page. I have modified following things

config.xml

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_category_abstract>Customization_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract</catalog_category_abstract>
                <permissions_user_grid>Customization_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Grid</permissions_user_grid>
                <permissions_user_edit_tab_main>Customization_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main</permissions_user_edit_tab_main>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <customization_adminhtml>
            <class>Customization_Adminhtml_Block</class>
        </customization_adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

I have created Folder Structure
app\code\local\Customization\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category
Catalog\Category\Abstract.php page

```
include "Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Abstract.php";
class Customization_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract
{
```

Comment: Without knowing why you want to do this we wont be able to help, but you cannot rewrite abstract classes in this way.

Comment: @DavidManners: uff!! interesting. can I know why it is not possible to rewrite abstract classes ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt short answer is cause they are never used via getModel where the rewrite "magic" happens.

Comment: @DavidManners : confused! getModel is used to get a model class. This is a block class. Then what is the ralation between these two. Can you give some hint on where that "magic" hapends. I will do dig then :)

Comment: @programmer_rkt sorry for the confusion. Same applies to blocks just a different function. The abstract for either block or model is only used in classes extends with the full name so Magento cannot rewrite it.

Comment: @DavidManners: now it makes sense. Need to confirm this by dig it more through code. Can you provide some hint.. means where to start atleast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YKJ,Any `Abstract class cannot not be override`.

If,you want modify any thing then just copy  Abstract to app/code/local directory...

As `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract` want  to overwrite.So copy

Abstract.php from  `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category`
to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category
```

As Magento `logic magento have taken file from local` folder(`app/code/local/`) then

from app/code/core/.
Magento have taken

```
Abstract class from local folder
```

Comment: Please do not do this. It could/will cause issues when upgrading Magento

Comment: i know that.As he/she want to do this so,,i have put my some concept

Comment: Thanks to all for answer. Right now for temporary work it works fine.

Comment: Instead, you can override the class that extends the abstract class you want to override.
*Example:*
`abstract class MyAbstractClass extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract {
//TODO: your methods ovverides or new ones
}`

`
class ClassThatExtendsClassYouWantToOverride extends MyAbstractClass {
//TODO: your logic
}
`

Answer (score 5):

What I would do in this case is to rewrite the class that you are actually dealing with and not the abstract class. The reasoning behind not being to rewrite abstract classes is because:

> [Basically these are the classes that are not instantiated in the application. They are used just to create other classes with common behavior.](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.de/2011/09/why-cant-you-override-some-classes-in.html)

These classes are not called by `Mage::getModel` or via the `type` attribute in layout.xml so they are not part of the rewriting that Magento does.

As mentioned I would look for the class that extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract` and rewrite this class this will make it easier for you to upgrade Magento to a new version at a later date.

Comment: super...............

Comment: @David - I've got the same problem and tried to do what you recommended; however, my solution doesn't seem to be working.  Would you mind having a quick glance at:http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75713/extending-an-abstract-block-class  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Best way which I found, 
Abstract class must be extended from some class.
**For example**

`class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract` is extended from ->

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract
```

in above situation, override `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form` and place function in that file.

this will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `config.xml` file seems to be ok (means rewrite part for `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract` block). However check these details

1. Ensure your rewriting block is in the location `app\code\local\Customization\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Abstract.php`
2. You dont need to include the block `Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Abstract.php` in rewrite block class, since Magento will do this for your when you extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract`.
3. Most importantly remove the unwanted space in the rewriting block class. (I can see some unwanted spaces after `extend`) In short the content should look like

   ```
    <?php
    class Customization_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract
    {
    //your method should come here
    }
   ```
4. You need to remove all cache. That is also an important step

Hope that will help you to resolve your problem